# Python - sanitizing href by character parsing

Tags: python, href

What I know:
A malicious user could do naughty things inside an href tag if he did something like:

```
<a href "www.somesite.com" [event] = ‘code’>
```

where the event is something like mouseover and code is something malicious.

I want to allow normal href, but remove anything between the `"` after `.com` and the `>` closing the href.
I was thinking of looking for the string `href`, counting 2 quotations and then deleting everything between the 2nd quotation and the `>`.

Would this work?  If so, how would I code that?

Comment: How are you expecting the user to "do naughty things inside an href tag"? Are you worried about people hacking your server using Greasemonkey or something? You'll need to give a more specific example of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

For a string called `input`, this expression gives you the position of the second double-quote character:

```
input.index('"', input.index('"')+1)
```

If that value is `k`, write `input[:k+1]` to extract everything up to and including the second double-quote character.

Try out the following in your Python interpreter.

```
input = 'href = "www.google.com" onmouseover=hax0rFunction()>'
k = input.index('"', input.index('"')+1)
input[:k+1]
```

Comment: Note that alternatively you could replace them with `&quot;`.